# How to convert formatted strings to float?

Tags: java, number-formatting, string-conversion

I have a list of strings and I'd like to convert them to float if a pattern is matched.

Here are some values and the expected result:

```
1000         -> 1000.0
1.000        -> 1000.0
1.000,000    -> 1000.0
-1.000,000   -> -1000.0
9,132        -> 9.132
1,000.00     -> invalid
30.10.2010   -> invalid
1,000.000,00 -> invalid
```

I tried this code for checking if a number is valid, but the pattern is never matched:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#.###,###");
for(String s : list){
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s); 
    if(m.matches()){
         //convert
    }
}
```

Beside that I've tried to use this code:

```
 DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
 for(String s : list){
        try {
            Number num = df.parse(s);
            //..
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        } 
    }
```

The problem with this code is, that no pattern-based validation is performed. E.g. a date like `2012/05/30` is converted to `2012`.

So how can I either define a valid pattern or configure `DecimalFormat` for my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The comments should explain it.

```
@Test
public void testAllValues() {
    testValue("1000", "1000");
    testValue("1.000,000", "1000");
    testValue("-1.000,000", "-1000");
    testValue("9,132", "9.132");
    testValue("1,000.00", null);
    testValue("30.10.2010", null);
    testValue("1,000.000,00", null);
}

private void testValue(String germanString, String usString) {
    BigDecimal germanDecimal = (BigDecimal) parse(germanString);
    if (usString != null) {
        BigDecimal usDecimal = new BigDecimal(usString);
        assertEquals("German " + germanString + " did not equal US " + usString, 0, germanDecimal.compareTo(usDecimal));
    } else {
        assertEquals("German " + germanString + " should not have been pareseable", null, germanDecimal);
    }
}

public BigDecimal parse(String s) {
    // Patch because parse doesn't enforce the number of digits between the
    // grouping character (dot).
    if (!Pattern.matches("[^.]*(\\.\\d{3})*[^.]*", s)) {
        return null;
    }

    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);

    // Have to use the ParsePosition API or else it will silently stop
    // parsing even though some of the characters weren't part of the parsed
    // number.
    ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
    BigDecimal parsed = (BigDecimal) df.parse(s, position);

    // getErrorIndex() doesn't seem to accurately reflect errors, but
    // getIndex() does reflect how far we successfully parsed.
    if (position.getIndex() == s.length()) {
        return parsed;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Pattern` class works with regular expressions. You probably want this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\d\.\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})?");
```

You probably want to tune this regex depending on exactly what formats you want or don't want to match.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.out.println("1,000.000,00".matches("^[+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d{3})*(,\\d+)?"));
```

I am not sure if your number can start with + so added it just in case. Also don't know if 0100000.000.000,1234 should be valid. If not tell why and regex will be corrected.

Comment: Strictly, the number you mentioned should not be valid, but I don't expect such a number ever to appear. So currently it works fine for filtering my list. Using your regex, I can't convert the strings using `DecimalFormat`, because if I change the regex, the format may not be correct anymore. So is there a way to convert the string to float based on regex?

Comment: @Pedro I've never worked with `DecimalFormat` so can't help you with that. Sorry. Only thing I can do for you now is customize regex more if it will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is the comma try:

```
String[] splitted = string.split(",")
```

If `size of splitted > 2` --> invalid.

If `splitted.size == 2 && splitted[1].split(".") > 0` --> invalid also.

If the format is fine --> remove all points, replace comma with point, parse string after comma into int and connect the pieces.

A very simple approach but it works...